# How can i get xtragrid row index via repository button in gridcell?

Tags: button, repository, devexpress, xtragrid

I have buttons in xtragrid cell . i want to get row index when i clicked to repository button item. How can i get cell info or index..

I wanna show cell info at anotherp page which respository button clicked in row cell..

Can you help me ?
Thanks for advice..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the information about Grid HitInfo check the [Hit Information Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument770) and [Samples of Using Hit Information](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument771) documentation:

```
private void gridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    // obtaining hit info 
    GridHitInfo hitInfo = gridView1.CalcHitInfo(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    if (((e.Button & MouseButtons.Right) != 0) && (hitInfo.InRow)  && 
        (!gridView1.IsGroupRow(hitInfo.RowHandle))) {
        // switching focus 
        gridView1.FocusedRowHandle = hitInfo.RowHandle;
        // showing the custom context menu 

        ViewMenu menu = new ViewMenu(gridView1);
        DXMenuItem menuItem = new DXMenuItem("DeleteRow", 
          new EventHandler(DeleteFocusedRow));
        menuItem.Tag = gridView1;
        menu.Items.Add(menuItem);
        menu.Show(hitInfo.HitPoint);
    }        
}
```

Check this:

```
private void repositoryItemButtonEdit_ButtonClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
{
    myGridView.DeleteRow(myGridView.FocusedRowHandle);  /// you can get focusedRowHandle here
}
```

Reference:
[Winforms XtraGrid Delete Row Button](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B207739.aspx)
[Delete button on each row of grid - how do we prevent the user from typing text in the new column with the delete button](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q150366.aspx)

**Edit:**
Refere this Devexpres thread:  [Cannot get the rowhandle to delete a row using RepositoryItemButtonEdit](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q295187.aspx)

Comment: this.repositoryItemButtonEdit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.repositoryItemButtonEdit_Click);

its giving error..
What i will write button events. i used
 this.repositoryItemButtonEdit.Click += new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventHandler(this.repositoryItemButtonEdit_Click);

Cannot implicitly convert type 'DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler' 

Thanks for answer.

Comment: check this..     `RepositoryItemButtonEdit rbtnEdit;
        private void SetLoopEdit()
        {
            rbtnEdit.Click += new EventHandler(rbtnEdit_Click);
            rbtnEdit.ButtonClick += new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventHandler(rbtnEdit_ButtonClick);` it should not raise any error.